# Laravel $request->has('name') doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started using laravel to learn how to use it. Currently, I am handling forms and looking at the different methods that Laravel offers to facilitate our work but I can not see why the following code does not work:

```
public function mensajes(Request $request) {
    //return $request->all();

    if ($request->has('nombre')){
        return "Sí tiene nombre. Es ". $request->input('nombre') ." y su correo es ". $request->input('email');
    } else {
        return "No tiene nombre";
    }



}
```

I try to verify that the form receives the input "name", but it receives it or not, it takes it as if it existed and if it was filled, however, when trying to execute this code if it does it correctly.

```
public function mensajes(Request $request) {
    //return $request->all();

    if ($request->input('nombre') != ''){
        return "Sí tiene nombre. Es ". $request->input('nombre') ." y su correo es ". $request->input('email');
    } else {
        return "No tiene nombre";
    }



}
```

I have a lot, maybe too much time watching my code, without seeing the error.

Comment: has checks if input exists in request array or not

Comment: But I have seen how they use it to check whether or not the input field has value, that is, if nothing is entered in that field of the form, I should make the second return of my code, but it does not work that way.

Comment: thats `if ($reques->get('name') !== null)`

Comment: I know it can be done in other ways, so I put the second code which works and does what I want, but I want to understand the use of has and because it does not work for me in the same way as the rest. If Has not do what I want, it will be version problems maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using `SanitizeMiddleware` laravel will keep the input name as property in the request as an empty string `("")` so `->has("name")` method will return `true` always.

Do the following, on console:

```
php artisan make:middleware SanitizeMiddleware
```

Then fill the new Middleware

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SanitizeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value) || $value == "") {
                if($value !== '0')
                $request->request->remove($key);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And register it on `Kernel`, within the web middleware group or wherever yo want to use it:

```
    /**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        SanitizeMiddleware::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

This will remove empty inputs from incoming request so `->has("")` should work now.

Answer (score 8):

Read **Laravel** docs attentively, for proper usage of the [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input).

**Determining If An Input Value Is Present**

You should use the has method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns true if the value is present on the request:

```
if ($request->has('name')) {
    //
}
```

If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use the filled method:

```
if ($request->filled('name')) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to test if the `nombre` property of the request object is a falsy value (ie. does not exist, is empty, or is `null`) by:

```
if($request->nombre) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```