# laravel request not redirect right page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a filter based on request `kelas` on database table. It gives me no error just when I click one of the filter, it don't show `jadwal` page with my filter. It show the main page but the url is right like `lps.com/?jadwal-2`

I have done make a middleware called `SanitizeMiddleware` from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517970/laravel-request-hasname-doesnt-work) but still not worked.

This is my route **web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@index');

Route::resource('pengumuman', 'PengumumanController');
Route::resource('jadwal', 'JadwalController');
Route::resource('rapot', 'RapotController');
```

This is my **index()** from my **JadwalController**

```
public function index()
{
    if (request()->has('kelas')) {
        $jadwal = jadwal::where('kelas', request('kelas')); 
    } else {
        $jadwal = jadwal::all();
    }

    return view('jadwal.index')->with('jadwal',$jadwal);

    //$jadwal = jadwal::all();
    //return view('jadwal.index')->with('jadwal',$jadwal);
}
```

This is my `index.blade.php`

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h1>
        <strong>Jadwal Pelajaran</strong>
    </h1>
    <a href="/?kelas=1">jadwwal kelas 1</a>
    <a href="/?kelas-2">jadwal kelas 2</a>
    <a href="/?kelas-3">jadwal kelas 3</a>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">07.00-08.00</th>
                <th scope="col">08.00-09.00</th>
                <th scope="col">09.00-10.00</th>
                <th scope="col">10.00-11.00</th>
                <th scope="col">10.00-12.00</th>
                <th scope="col">action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if(count($jadwal)>0)
                @foreach($jadwal as $jadwals)
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{$jadwals->hari}}</th>
                        <td>{{$jadwals->jamke1}}</td>
                        <td>{{$jadwals->jamke2}}</td>
                        <td>{{$jadwals->jamke3}}</td>
                        <td>{{$jadwals->jamke4}}</td>
                        <td>{{$jadwals->jamke4}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/jadwal/{{$jadwals->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <p>tidak ada jadwal</p>
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the picture of problem:-

this is my jadwal page before filter
[image: this is my jadwal page before filter]

this my page after i click the filter using request()
[image: this my page after i click the filter using request()]

Comment: HTML URL talking, `lps.com/?jadwal-2` is just calling the home page with a GET parameter called `jadwal-2` with no value at all. `lps.com/jadwal` is good, `lps.com/jadwal?kelas=2` is good. forget the dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just a simple url issue

as you see the list of **jadwal** is displayed in the route

```
lps.com/jadwal
```

What is the issue as you see

```
<a href="/?kelas=1">jadwwal kelas 1</a>
<a href="/?kelas=2">jadwal kelas 2</a>
<a href="/?kelas=3">jadwal kelas 3</a>
```

While Clicking this any of the link its redirecting to

For Example If i Clicked **jadwwal kelas 1**

```
lps.com/?kelas=1
```

So Its not redireting to lps.com/jadwal?kelas=1

So Try to change

```
<a href="jadwal/?kelas=1">jadwwal kelas 1</a>
<a href="jadwal/?kelas=2">jadwal kelas 2</a>
<a href="jadwal/?kelas=3">jadwal kelas 3</a>
```

And the final thing if you are using the pagination

```
{{$jadwal->links()}}
```

> This Will only add the ?page=yourCurrentPageNumber

But in Some situation You need both the filters and pagination

So Try below Method

```
{{$jadwal->appends(request()->input())->links()}}
```

It will appends all the `GET` Request Parameter

So If You need to vist the `nth page` of `kelas=1` its will work

Hope its helps

if you are facing and issue kindly comment below

Comment: thank you! it worked, and also thank you for pagination tips!

Comment: you are always welcome thank you for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

HTML URL talking, `lps.com/?jadwal-2` is just calling the home page with a GET parameter called `jadwal-2` with no value at all. `lps.com/jadwal` is good, `lps.com/jadwal?kelas=2` is good. forget the dash

Using `/` in href attribute tell the system to start from the the top level path. Change to relative like :

```
<a href="?kelas=1">jadwwal kelas 1</a>
<a href="?kelas-2">jadwal kelas 2</a>
<a href="?kelas-3">jadwal kelas 3</a>
```

So being on page `lps.com/jadwal` will result in url `lps.com/jadwal?kelas=1` which is the correct syntax and pattern.